# how to fix this Drupal\commerce\CommerceEntityViewsData' not found

Tags: commerce

installed Commerce reports using composer. On enabling the module got an error:
"Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\commerce\CommerceEntityViewsData' not found".
what is the solution for this i searched for CommerceEntityViewsData but i couldnot find what exactly it is please help me.
i'm a newbie
Thanks

Comment: Is your project structured using https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/? Did you installed commerce_reports using `composer require drupal/commerce_reports`?

Comment: yes i installed using composer require drupal/commerce_reports only also the project is structured using drupal-composer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using [Drupal Commerce 8.x-2.6+](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/releases/8.x-2.6)
CommerceEntityViewsData was added in https://www.drupal.org/node/2882374

Comment: not able to update commerce to 8.6 from 8.3  give error for commerce_product

Comment: What kind of error? How do you update the module?